# Ideal model structure for an ASP.NET MVC project for handeling multiple partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have two partial views named as `_centerDetails.cshtml` and `_centerRights.cshtml` .

I am passing data from `centerdetails` when I click on submit and want to show this when another partial view is switched, but without posting it to the server.

> This is my model class which I have created to handling my data via
>   controller:

```
namespace ADWP_AdminWebPortal.Models
{

    public class CountryList
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a Country.")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a State.")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a City.")]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerDetails: CountryList
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage="Eneter the First name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Eneter the Middle name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set;}
        public string NatureOfOccupation { get; set; }

        public string AgentId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Select a Client Type.")]
        public string ClientType { get; set; }

        public int TariffId { get; set; }
        public string TariffName { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public int PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethodName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here you can see the mess I have created. My problem is how to handle multiple models when you are working with multiple models in same controller?

Here I did not created all the data in a single class because I wanted it to reuse as per my need.

> How can I handling data in a model? This is the main problem that is
>   coming to me while I am creating the partial views in my project.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: You don't have duplicated records in your table!  Were you perhaps thinking of converting your tables to a format that's compliant with the 2nd normal form?

Comment: in your example Robin appears twice but has 2 different Costs(that is not duplicate), do you perhaps want the maximum COST? in that case just use MAX(), and group by name and type

Comment: @NishantKumar i showed that in reults

Comment: @Stephen you raised good point that means i can only delete that particular record if i grouped the records.

Comment: yes exactly, that is I am trying @e4c5. is this possible?

Comment: why don't you edit your question to reflect that

Comment: please edit your question, otherwise I will have to down vote it

Comment: @Stephen have you any suggestion for this?

Comment: @didxga can you tell me now when I have edited and made the question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of a struggle I got the result.

```
 public class CountryList
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a Country.")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    // Added Class

public class State
{
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a State.")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }
}
    // Added Class
public class City
{
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a City.")]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
}

    public class CustomerDetails
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage="Enter the first name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the middle name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }


        public int TariffId { get; set; }
        public string TariffName { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public int PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethodName { get; set; }
        public List<CountryList> { get; set; } //added list
        public List<State> { get; set; } //added list
        public List<City> { get; set; } //added list

        }
```

Yeah, it was so easy.

Answer (score 2):

You may use CTE and ROW_NUMBER function together to delete duplicate rows from your table.

```
With CTE AS (
    SELECT VERIFICATIONTYPE,
            NAME,
            COST,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VERIFICATIONTYPE, NAME, COST ORDER BY VERFICATIONTYPE)
    FROM DETAILS)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
END
```

Comment: Why do you think this will not work? Would you explain? @rajan-mishra